# getting average of column and value of another mysql

Tags: mysql, select, average

I'm not sure if the title I'm using is correct but let me explain what is happening.
I have a table with exchange rates that are updated daily.  Here's the table:

```
DateCreated |  Bank  |  Buy
2013-10-09  |  tc    |  2.40
2013-10-09  |  bank1 |  2.45
2013-10-09  |  bank2 |  2.46
2013-10-09  |  bank3 |  2.45
```

So what i need is a comparison by average compared to the "tc" bank so like this:

```
Date        | tc    |  banks
2013-10-09  | 2.40  |  2.453   <- this is the average of all three banks for that date
```

hope this makes sense, here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT e.datecreated, e.buy, (SELECT AVG(buy) FROM exchange WHERE idbank <>  'tc'
AND datecreated = e.datecreated) AS banks
FROM exchange e
WHERE idbank =  'tc'
ORDER BY e.datecreated ASC
```

but this is dumping duplicates and it seems like wrong data..help?

Comment: what is 'idbanco' and 'idbank'?

Comment: sorry i was translating my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the specified result:

```
SELECT e.datecreated
     , MAX(IF(e.idbank='tc',e.buy,NULL)) AS tc
     , AVG(IF(e.idbank='tc',NULL,e.buy)) AS banks
  FROM exchange e
 GROUP BY e.datecreated
```

There are lots of other queries that will return an equivalent result.